# AndroidX biometrics force fingerprint

Tags: androidx, biometrics

Is it possible to force the AndroidX biometrics library to make use of fingerprint, rather than other mechanisms? Right now, some Samsung devices are forcing our app to use Iris instead of fingerprint, even if the user prefers fingerprints

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there isn't. I've filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641) about that, but haven't really received any response yet.